# AMP auto-ads not working

Tags: adsense, amp-html

I am having trouble finding the cause why adsense auto ads will not load on my amp pages. As far as I can tell the required code was added to the head and body section of the amp pages and while other ads load fine the auto ads don't.

Here are some example urls. Thank you for your help and feedback.

https://www.enotalone.com/forum/amp.php?t=539953

https://www.enotalone.com/forum/amp.php?t=544906

Comment: Have you seen this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/amphtml-discuss/Xqpm-73piYQ)?